# Area of isosceles triangle

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I need to solve following problem:

> The vertex of the isosceles triangle $ABC$ is the point $A(-1, 0)$, and the vertices $B$ and $C$ belong to the parabola $y^2 = 4x$. If the point $(0, 0)$ is the orthocenter of triangle $ABC$, then its area is equal to ?

I've tried to use fact that points C and B lies on parabola to express their coordinates $B(x,2\sqrt x)$ and $C(x,-2\sqrt x)$

Also i can express height and area of triangle as:
Area = $2\sqrt{x}(x+1)$.
Height = $x+1$

Can you help me to figure it out ?

Comment: What is your definition of orthocenter?

Comment: It is cross-point of triangle heights

Comment: I found a way to make progress with vectors, since we can write out the information given to us by $(0, 0)$ being the orthocenter in terms of the dot product, which sets up a system of equations. Are you familiar with vectors, and the dot product? (I'm still looking for a more geometrical answer if you'd prefer that)

Comment: I take it you mean intersection of the three altitudes of the triangle. Right?

Comment: What do you mean by isosceles? Does that mean AB=AC or BC=AB or CA=BC?

Comment: @Siddharth If the orthocenter and $A$ are both on the x-axis, then $BC$ must be vertical. This, plus the restrictions on $B$ and $C,$ give us that $AB = AC.$

Comment: @StephenDonovan Yes, My bad :-| !

Comment: @Siddharth No worries, it's easy to just assume that would have to be the case because it looks like it should, but it is the kind of thing which we should prove to be certain

Comment: @StephenDonovan yes absolutely!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume $B(t^2,2t)$ and $C(t^2,-2t)$ as $AB=AC$, Where $t>0$.

As you said orthocentre is $H(0,0)$, it implies that,

$m_{BH}\cdot m_{AC}=-1$

> Where $m_l$ represents slope of line $l$.

Or,

$$\left(\frac{2t-0}{t^2-0}\right)\left(\frac{-2t-0}{t^2+1}\right)=-1$$$$\implies t=\sqrt{3}$$

> As $t>0$

So, area will be
$$ \frac{1}{2} (1+t^2)(4t)=\boxed{8\sqrt{3}}$$

> $\frac{1}{2}×$*distance from $A$ to $BC$*$×BC$

Comment: Good job, this is actually pretty close to my approach in the way it uses the perpendicularity information but gets rid of the reliance on vectors which mine has, so it's probably better for this question. (I hope you don't mind that I'll be posting my approach as an answer now, I've given up the ghost on finding a less algebraic way to do it)

Comment: @StephenDonovan No, Sir why would I mind a human should take as much knowledge as possible. Your method is absolutely fantastic. You developed a new approach in my mind that these question can be solved by vectors. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 4):

Since another more algebraic answer was posted, I see no reason not to also post my original attempt. It requires some more complex geometrical concepts, but also a bit less algebra.

Suppose $B$ has coordinates $(x, y).$ We would then have $\vec{AB} = \langle x + 1, y\rangle,$ since we're going from $(-1, 0)$ to $(x, y).$

Note that by symmetry we have that $\vec{C} = \langle x, -y\rangle,$ and that because the origin is the orthocenter of the triangle, $\vec{C}$ is orthogonal to $\vec{AB},$ so

$$\vec{C} \cdot \vec{AB} = \langle x + 1, y\rangle \cdot \langle x, -y\rangle = (x + 1)(x) + (y)(-y) = x^2 + x - y^2 = 0$$

Now recalling that our restriction on $B$ requires that $y^2 = 4x,$ we have

$$x^2 + x - 4x = 0 \Rightarrow x^2 - 3x = 0 \Rightarrow x = 0 \text{ or } x = 3$$

and because $x = 0$ would give us a degenerate triangle, we must have $x = 3.$ From here we can proceed the same way as the other answer, showing that our triangle has altitude $4$ and base $4\sqrt{3},$ so its area is $$\frac12 \cdot 4 \cdot 4\sqrt{3} = \boxed{8\sqrt{3}}$$

Comment: A beautiful solution!

Comment: @Siddharth Thank you, I'm glad you enjoyed it

Comment: @Stephendonowan :-)

Answer (score 2):

Given that the line connecting $B$ to the origin is $y = mx$, $y^2 = 4x$ gives $m^2 x^2 - 4x = 0$ $ \implies x(m^2 x - 4) = 0$, so the other intersections apart from $(0, 0)$ are when $x = \frac{4}{m^2}$, and $y = \pm \frac{4}{m}$.

Now finding the equation of the perpendicular which must pass through $(-1, 0)$, we have:

$$y - 0 = -\frac{1}{m} (x - -1)$$
$$-\frac{4}{m} = -\frac{1}{m} (\frac{4}{m^2} + 1)$$
$$-4m^2 = -4 - m^2$$
$$4 = 3m^2, m^2 = 4/3$$

and thus $x = 4/(4/3) = 3$ leading to an area of $2 \sqrt{3} (3 + 1) = \boxed{8 \sqrt3}$.

Comment: Despite the extra algebra I quite like this approach as well, given that the key element of the lines being perpendicular can be written in terms of the slopes working in terms of it explicitly like this seems pretty natural and logical. Nice work